# I have issues in my wp dashboard

Tags: wordpress

Please have a look on Screen shot my dashboard (left side logo)

[image]

Comment: yeah so whats wrong

Comment: Look your browser console. Looks like loading dashicons return error.

Comment: Please have a look on left side icons. all wordpress dashboard icon not displaying

Answer (score 0):

Looks like icons are not loading for some reason. 
Go to your wp-config.php file and add these two lines:

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);

define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
```

After that look for the following line in your .htaccess file:

```
php_value memory_limit 64M
```

Also make sure that you're not [overriding any of the Font-Awesome](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/249136/icons-not-showing) fonts with your custom css.